# Laravel API - Display all districts when state field is empty

Tags: laravel, postgresql, api, laravel-8, rest

Below given is my code to display the specific districts of an inputted state. But in this code itself, i want to display all districts in the db if the state field is empty. How to modify my code to get such an output. So, my desired API works such that it returns all the districts when the api is called. And only if the state field is inputted, it shows the particular districts specific to it. Help me with ur suggestions.

```
public function state_lookup(Request $request)
{
     $validator = Validator::make
    ($request->all(),
        [
            'state'     => 'string',
        ]
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(
            [$validator->errors()],
            422
        );
    }

    if(empty($request->state)){
        $dist=PersonalDetails::get(['district']);
        return response()->json($dist);
    }

    $data = PersonalDetails::where('state',$request->state)->get(['district']);
 // dd($data);
    if(count($data)){

        return response()->json(['message'=>'success','data'=>$data]);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Invalid State']);
    }
}
```

in failure case,I am getting json result as below

```
    {
    "message": "success",
    "data": []
}
```

it shows "success" instead of "invalid state"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `when`

```
$data = PersonalDetails::when(!empty($request->state),function ($query)use($request){
        $query->where('state',$request->state);
    })->get(['district']);
```

or

```
   $data = PersonalDetails::where(function ($query)use($request){
        if(isset($request)&&!empty($request)){
            $query->where('state',$request->state);
        }
       
    })->get(['district']);
```

To avoid 0 key in response change like below

```
if(count($data)){

   return response()->json(['message'=>'success','data'=>$data]);
}
```

Comment: See the update question. why there is a '0' in my  success meassage. i don't want it to appear. How to eliminate it?

Comment: I am getting "success" in invalid case too. why it is so? Please see my updated question

Comment: @MG updated answer. let me know if any issues

Comment: no change for the result even after adding the count($data)

Comment: @MG.check your code again .it should work. it goes to if condition only if it has atleast one data or else it goes to else condition

Comment: I have tested with `dd($data);` .it shows all districts when no state name is inputted but not showing the district when a particular state is inputted.

Comment: make sure it should match exact word in db for state or lese it return empty .so dd($request->state) and also if you are not searching exact keyword then use $query->where('state','%'.$request->state.'%');

Comment: I don't know where i am wrong. it just shows success message in the invalid case as i have given in my question .Except that everything works fine

Comment: @MG.not sure how your actual code .as per me it goes to else case if its empty array from $data

Comment: Now it's works fine. Don't know why it was not working before

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
//In your controller
$request->validate([
   'state' => 'string'
]);

// $request->validate it self return error messages you have to display 
// for an example (write below code in your blade file)
@error('state')
  <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror

// write below code in your controller file
 $details = PersonalDetails::select('district');

 $details->where(function($query) use($request) {
       if (isset($request->state) && $request->state != '') {
          $query->where('state', $request->state);
       }
       // do what you want to filter in your query like above
 });

 $data = $details->get();
```